# Python Sympy Solve - how can I call a number of equations dynamically?

Tags: python, math, sympy, equation

I was working on some linear equation problems regarding spline function, which already exists in our beautiful Python library, but the thing is that my professor requested me to find out the every coefficients of spline function so that I can fully understand its mathematical structure.

As a result, I came out with some simultaneous linear equations - the number of equations depend on the user input.

So I allocated my variables dynamically so that if the user declares he/she will utilize 3 points, it prints out 3 equations, and if declare 4 points, prints out 4 equations, and so on.
and now I have to solve these equations without even knowing how many equations there will be.

I searched some methods for solving linear equations using solve of Sympy, but none of them were showing me how to call these equations dynamically, depending on the user input.

All articles were saying like, oh it's easy, you can write as:
solve((eq1, eq2), dict=True)

but mine will be like :
solve((eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, ... )
and the variables will be also like (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, ...)

I was trying to use 'eq{}'.format(i) to call all the 'eq{}'s I made, but systematically failed for the reason I don't know.

How can I call all the equations and variables I made in 'solve' method dynamically?

I'm a newbie to Python, please help me......

Comment: Looks like `solve` takes a tuple (or list) of equations.  Create that list first. Same for a list of symbols.

Comment: In general in Python the "dynamic" behavior that you seek is achieved with lists, and if necessary `dict`, rather than naming variables `eq1, eq2, ...`.  `sympy` modifies this by allowing you to create a **`tuple`** with `symbols('x:10')`.  You can unpack it to variables, but you don't have to.

Comment: I suggest looking at a basic Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are not symbolic variables other than the ones for which you want to solve, then my favorite way of getting the symbols is:

```
def neq(n):
   return list or tuple containing the n equations

from sympy import Tuple, solve
eqs = Tuple(*neq(n))
syms = eqs.free_symbols
sol = solve(eqs, syms)
```

You will get back a single dictionary (or a list of dictionaries) with the mapping for the `symbol: solution`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made it! I'm not familiar to the list type yet... maybe I should practice more on basic grammar haha XD